# Wix toolset HKMU vs HKCR, HKMU writes to HKCR, HKCR not visible but works

Tags: wix

I am doing file associations in Wix Toolset, really simple like:

```
<RegistryValue Root="HKMU"
Key="SOFTWARE\Classes\.myfile" Value="myfile" Type="string"/>
<RegistryValue Root="HKMU"
Key="SOFTWARE\Classes\myfile" Value="MyFileTypeInWindowsExplorer" Type="string"/>
```

I am confused - using both HKMU and HKCR it works, but reading the limited dokumentation, such as http://akashche.github.io/wixgen/wixgen-jaxb/apidocs/com/redhat/akashche/wixgen/jaxb/RegistryRootType.html my logic tells me to use HKCR and not HKMU
However I see other people use HKMU, and yes it writes to CLASSES_ROOT where I find my association. I just dont get why HKMU writes to CLASSES_ROOT when it should write to CURRENT_USER - unless my installation is for current user only.
So using HKCR - which is for CLASSES_ROOT - it should write to that, but I cannot see it, however it works, meaning that it is there, but not visible to me?

So, I somehow get this but yet I am scratching my head. Dokumentation is limited.

Can anyone explain about the options for RegistryRootType in Wix Toolset?

Thanks
Sonnich

Answer (score 0):

When reading the registry HKCR is a merged view of HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes and HKCU\SOFTWARE\Classes of the process owner profile who is viewing the registry.   In Windows Installer if you use the COM Tables (ClassId, ProgId, AppId, TypeLib ) or registry HCKR it will take into consideration the scope of the installation (Per Machine vs Per User) and write to the appropriate location.

For HKCU\SOFTWARE vs HKLM\SOFTWARE there is no merge and HKMU is used to designate which you wish to write to.

Note: Most MSIs are authored for Per-Machine.  Per-User and  Single Package Per-User/Per-Machine installations are a very advanced topic with limited use case so it's possible you are overthinking this.  It's also possible you your need this functionality.